# Нужно ли тире? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, тире, приложение, уточнения

Должно ли стоять тире в (1)? В каком случае под номером (2) будет тире и почему? 
Как мне кажется, второй вариант правильный, и под номерами (1) и (2) будет стоять тире, но правильно ли в таком случае обособление? Т. е. "это может быть только один человек" приобретает пояснительно-уточняющее значение.

1) Он также рассказал про выжившего, которого держат в одной из камер (1)  это может быть только твой друг (2) Мартин!

2) Он также рассказал про выжившего, которого держат в одной из камер (1) это может быть только один человек (2) твой друг Мартин!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно ли стоять тире в (1)?

Тире может стоять в (1). Сначала ставим запятую, завершая придаточное предложение *которого держат в одной из камер*. После него ставим тире, так как далее идёт предложение со значением вывода, следствия.

***1). Он также рассказал про выжившего, которого держат в одной из камер, - (1) это может быть только твой друг (2) Мартин!***

[ТИРЕ в БСП, примечание](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=425) Запятую и тире как единый знак препинания не следует смешивать с сочетанием этих знаков, когда тире разграничивает части бессоюзного сложного предложения, а запятая отделяет впереди стоящую обособленную конструкцию или придаточную часть предложения: ***Не прошло и трех часов с восхода солнца, а уж казалось, что близок полдень, — так жарко, светло было всюду и так многолюдно возле лавок в конце улицы (Бун.); Крупнолицый парень, моторист баркаса, равнодушным взором поглядывал в пасмурное небо, включил мотор, и мгновенно всё успокоилось, затихло в воде, плотно оцепленной лодками, — ни всплеска, ни шума, ни сверкания*** (Бонд.).

В **1)** предложении интонационное **тире** на месте **2)** возможно при условии, если автор делает значительную паузу перед словом МАРТИН.

Второе предложение нужно оформить так:

***2) Он также рассказал про выжившего, которого держат в одной из камер, - (1) это может быть только один человек - (2) твой друг Мартин!***

Тире (2) перед обособленным приложением ***твой друг Мартин*** ставим, так как приложение распространённое и стоит в конце предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Первое предложение.
На месте (1) необходимо поставить запятую (она закрывает придаточное предложение) и тире, так как вторая часть бессоюзного предложения имеет присоединительный характер (с пояснительным оттенком значения).

Если не знать контекста, то имя *Мартин* может восприниматься как обращение. Тогда на месте (2) нужна запятая (*...это может быть только твой друг, Мартин!*).
Во избежание такого восприятия предложение лучше записать так:
**Он также рассказал про выжившего, которого держат в одной из камер, — это может быть только Мартин, твой друг!**

Второе предложение.
Да, на месте (2), перед приложением *твой друг Мартин* (не таким уж и распространенным), стоящим в самом конце предложения, можно (но не обязательно) ставить тире.
Но тогда их будет два и визуально часть предложения между двумя тире может восприниматься как вставка.

Я бы оформила предложение таким образом (с первым тире):
**Он также рассказал про выжившего, которого держат в одной из камер, — это может быть только один человек, твой друг Мартин!**

Или таким (со вторым тире):
**Он также рассказал про выжившего, которого держат в одной из камер. Это может быть только один человек — твой друг Мартин!**

[Запятая и тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=107#pp107)
[Обособление приложений](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/718-242_obosoblenie_prilozhenii.html)

Comment: Да, в этом случае не обращение, но спасибо за пояснение и такого варианта.